# How is a wealthy criminal expected to get a good lawyer?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, california, lawyer, attorney-client-relationship

Say Carl the criminal is a bad guy who's rich. One day, he gets caught. They confiscate his phone and lock him up and deny bail. How is Carl supposed to find a good lawyer? He's locked up and doesn't have access to the internet or even his phone contacts. To be clear, he has tons of money that the very best lawyers would work for. But it means nothing if he can't search online for who's good, etc.

Or is it the case that they let Carl use a laptop and access Yelp or something to look for good lawyers?

Comment: Why do you think he can’t have visitors or make a phone call from jail?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Carl would want to shop around for a good lawyer, right? He can't just hope the best lawyer money can buy happens to visit him. Nor can he be expected to have memorized the number of that amazing lawyer.

Comment: @chausies nope, he'd already have a lawyer under retainer, probably more than one, who will be under orders to find out what's happened to him if he can't be reached and doesn't contact them for more than say 24 hours without prior communication that he'll be out of contact.

Comment: Good lawyers are not sitting around waiting for clients to show up. They have existing clients that they actively take care of. If Carl got arrested, a **really good** lawyer might be waiting at the station for him.

Comment: Police are required to provide a list of lawyers and allow the defendant to make calls on station phones to lawyers (You don't have a right to "one phone call", but most cops are more than happy to give you as many as you need.  They do have to let you contact a lawyer and they can't say "no more calls" if the call fails to connect.).

Comment: Just for the record as I understand it you loose your cell phone but usually do have access to a monitored phone, and I *believe* they would usually allow you to request looking at the cell phone long enough to look up a number from the contacts, judging from my grand experience of one friend ending up in jail for a day over a forgotten traffic ticket and *allot* of disorganization and unfortunate coincidences.  Point is you could still call mom and dad and ask them to get you a lawyer presumable.

Comment: You left out the part where they freeze all Carl's assets and he can no longer afford a lawyer.

Answer (score 54):

If Carl is rich, he already has a lawyer.

Even if he doesn't already have a lawyer, he can hire the first lawyer he finds to find him another lawyer more to his liking.

Comment: This is very often how it works. As a lawyer who does not criminal work myself, I have trusted quality criminal lawyers in my contact list that I refer people like my non-criminal case clients to when a client or someone they know needs one. I have a little "emergency legal response" spiel to tide my clients over for a few days until they can get a real criminal lawyer. When my kids were teen, I gave them a business card from one of them to carry with them just in case.

Comment: Is it common for lawyers to recommend their own competitors when the client requests it? I can't imagine, say, going to a car mechanic and asking for recommendations for other car mechanics (unless the issue I have is one that the first mechanic can't help me with).

Comment: @TannerSwett A criminal-defense lawyer is not a competitor of a lawyer who handles contracts and wills, or taxes. Different kinds of lawyers.

Comment: It is very common to make such referrals. There are often agreements in place by which the referring lawyer may get a cut of the client's fee.

Comment: @TannerSwett not just do not all lawyers do all work, and will refer clients to colleagues who are specialised in specific fields, but most if not all lawyers are not licensed to work in more than a limited number of jurisdictions and will refer clients to colleagues who are licensed in the jurisdiction where they are needed.

Comment: @TannerSwett quite some lawyers are part of a larger law firm and can point to their colleagues. Others have worked so long with their court opponents that they are friends outside of court. And some would refer to their worst nightmare in the courtroom because they know that those lawyers are actually just really good at their job or better than them.

Comment: @Davislor Indeed, and that's why I asked the question that I did. Reading this answer made me wonder if it's common for lawyers to recommend their own *competitors* – other lawyers who do the same type of work, are licensed in the same jurisdiction, and don't work for the same law firm.

Comment: @TannerSwett Yes. This happens every day. When a new client calls, I'm far more likely to refer them out to a competitor than to actually work with them. I may not have the time, or the legal questions may be better suited to someone with a different specialty, or the venue may be one where I don't want to do work, even though I'm licensed there.

Comment: This question fully answers the question as asked, but it still begs the related question of how a non filthy rich person is suppose to get an attorney.  A carrier criminal may already 'know a guy', but a regular person off the street accused of a crime who has no knowledge of any attorneys still seems kind of screwed if they want something more then a court appointed attorney.  I imagine they either need to call a friend and ask the friend to do the leg work, or ask their court appointed attorney to help them find a paid one?

Comment: @bdb484 I thought that it was considered unethical for a lawyer to receive direct compensation just for a referral?  Am I misreading rule 7.2b of the ABA Model Rules of Professional Conduct? https://www.americanbar.org/groups/professional_responsibility/publications/model_rules_of_professional_conduct/rule_7_2_advertising/

Comment: @Chuu The rules vary from state to state, but the bottom line is that lawyers have unsurprisingly found ways to get around the rules that govern their behavior.

Comment: @dsollen State bar associations have lawyer referral services with lists of lawyers for different needs. Often the lawyer has to agree to provide a free consultation to be on the list. You also had the phone book, back in the day.

Comment: @dsollen: You could combine the two. Take the court-appointed attorney up front, then ask them to pass a message to your friend who can do legwork. Then switch attorneys once the friend finds a good one.

Comment: @TannerSwett I have used the same automobile maintenance company for decades (I've probably paid for one of their boats over the decades), but they don't do body shop work. A few years ago "I fought the wall and the wall won" (the wall of my house, that is, with my truck), and it resulted a big scratch on the vehicle. When I asked "where can I get this scratch removed" they gladly provided a reference, no charge. Contract lawyers and criminal lawyers similarly know rather different parts of the law. Good lawyers will give references because they aren't competitors.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes, I know that, and that's _why_ I used the word "competitors" in my question.

Answer (score 10):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Everyone who has been arrested and is held in custody at a police station is entitled to free and independent legal advice (FILA) - see [section 58](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1984/60/section/58?timeline=false) Police and Criminal Evidence Act 1984 (PACE).

If Carl doesn't know of, or can't contact, a solicitor he can get one from the on-call duty solicitor list available from the custody officer at the police station.

Comment: But then Carl is at the mercy of a list curated by people who want him imprisoned, no? There's no reason to expect he'd find the best lawyers money can buy on that list. In the extreme case, what's stopping that list from being filled with mediocre lawyers that barely pass?

Comment: @chausies Things work differently this side of the Atlantic!

Comment: fair enough >.<

Comment: @chausies Carl is entitled to *a* lawyer; he isn’t entitled to the *best* unless he sources that himself

Comment: @Chausies: On top of what Dale M said - if he has a truly mediocre lawyer that barely passes, he theoretically is allowed to appeal on ineffective counsel; though there is a limit to what ineffective counsel counts as, it *does* exist as a method to handle an outcome in the extreme case. The cost of handling said appeals, even if they fail, is what stops that list from being filled with mediocre lawyers that barely pass.

Comment: @chausies the court appointed lawyer is typically one who dreams of winning a big case so they can draw the attention of a prestigious law firm and get hired at a much higher salary, or they're dreamers who take the job on principal of "wanting to see justice" and don't mind the poor salary. All those people will usually do their best for the client, or find someone who can do better.

Comment: @DaleM but that's what the question is about: is he entitled to be allowed to source the best himself?

Comment: It's actually not that different in the US.  We have Public Defenders, whose job it is to represent people who cannot afford a lawyer.  It's even in the Miranda rights: *"You have the right to an attorney.  If you cannot afford an attorney, one will be provided for you by the state."*  But of course Carl *can* afford a lawyer, and probably a much better one than what the state will provide.  Probably a whole *team* of such lawyers in fact.

Comment: This only answers the question of how Carl finds _a_ lawyer, not how Carl can find a _good_ lawyer once he's been arrested. It seems unlikely that a rich criminal would be using the duty solicitor.

Comment: @chausies - "*The Duty Solicitor Scheme is now more accurately called the Criminal Litigation Accreditation Scheme and is administered by the Law Society. All members of the scheme must reach a certain standard before they are admitted to it.*".  In the UK, the standard of Duty Solicitors is invariably pretty high and the State has little or no control over who gets chosen to be a Duty Solicitor, other than from 'arm's length' by setting the standards required.

Comment: @Richard The US has the same, states have an Indigent Defense Council/Commission/Office and most require special training and accreditation. None of this affects the core issues of pay and workload: high-priced lawyers can charge millions of dollars for a serious case (OJ Simpson racked up $5 million in 1995), which naturally causes those not to participate in public defense. Beyond that, there are other fields of law that pay very well and it's well known that criminal defense is very stressful.

Comment: I'd assume this is the same in the UK, in the US public defenders get a bad rap but they're often good at getting people the best bail conditions possible and negotiating decent deals with prosecutors because they do it every day.  Once Mr. Moneybags is out on bond he can freely get an attorney of his choosing.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, police and prosecution want convictions to happen and stick. They do not want convictions tossed out by an appeals court on the argument that the defendant was denied access to counsel.

As such, the authorities will bend over backwards to make sure the defendant has access to independent counsel.

Now that the defendant has a lawyer sworn to serve their legal interests, they now have a minion on the outside who will serve their requirements, certainly including recruiting more high-powered counsel.

Answer (score 4):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Carl has a right to have someone informed of his arrest (PACE, section 56):

> Where a person has been arrested and is being held in custody in a police station or other premises, he shall be entitled, if he so requests, to have one friend or relative or other person who is known to him or who is likely to take an interest in his welfare told, as soon as is practicable except to the extent that delay is permitted by this section, that he has been arrested and is being detained there.

He should choose as that person someone he expects to find and engage the most suitable lawyer (or to make sure that happens), as well as to collect the children, feed the chickens and turn off the oven.